# II6 websites stop responding

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, web-hosting

We have 3 Windows 2003 servers (IIS6) running from 20 to 30 ASP.net websites each.  These servers are VMware VMs.  Periodically all of the websites on a server will become unreachable from the outside.  In the browser I get **Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset** for all of the sites on that server.

I have tried restarting IIS and/or recycling the app pool.  So far I have seen nothing in the logs.  Restarting the server has been the fix so far but it can take 20 minutes for 30 websites to recompile.  We have attempted to resolve this with the host but they monitor the server itself which is running and never trips their monitors.  They are useless at this point.

Any ideas?   Are there other services I can restart rather than a full reboot?  Is there another place in the network or system I can check?  I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, what about updating to a current System, preferably 64 bit`? Then you can run all that on 3 virtual machines on a low end Server, pretty much.

You can restart IIS only by forcing a command line iisreset, but i Think you may have to start looking for the root cause - some error somewhere. Does not help that you use a Technology that is no 4 generatiosn behind, IIS wise (7.0, 7.5, 8.0), so you are pretty much on your own and MS Paid Support ;(

Comment: I have tried the iisreset but it doesn't fix the problem.   I know there is a root cause somewhere which is why I posted this for some suggestions of a root cause.

Comment: Also, we are working on establishing a relationship with a new host so I will make sure the new servers are 64-bit.  I can't imagine they wouldn't be but I will make sure.